# Error while loading YAML model file using opencv in android

Tags: opencv, java-native-interface, android

I am using opencv for facial landmark detection in android. I am using JNI for interaction with library. I have saved "lbfmodel.yaml" file in assets and trying to load :

```
const char* jnamestr2 = jenv->GetStringUTFChars(jModelFileName, NULL);
cv::String stdFileName2(jnamestr2);
LOGD( "jModelFileName path : %s", jnamestr2);
FacemarkLBF::Params params;
params.model_filename = stdFileName2;
params.cascade_face = stdFileName;
Ptr<FacemarkLBF> facemark = FacemarkLBF::create(params);
```

But I am receiving error :

```
Invalid address 0x9b2d2e08 passed to free: value not allocated
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 27673
```

I have logged the filepath and it is :

```
jModelFileName path : /data/user/0/com.ds.openworld/app_model/lbfmodel.yaml
```

I don't know what is the issue because it is crashing in native part. The model file is also large. Is that an issue?

Please help!

Comment: Can you try with some smaller file size ?

Comment: Well in my case the version of the database caused a similar error.(Not OpenCV, but tesseract..) How about re-searching for the database, which matches the version of the library?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can't directly use a file which is stored as an asset, you first need to convert it to a "regular" file. Use the following code snippet for that:

```
public String initAssetFile(String filename)  {
    File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);
    if (!file.exists()) try {
        InputStream is = getAssets().open(filename);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] data = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(data); os.write(data); is.close(); os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    Log.d(TAG,"prepared local file: "+filename);
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Original source: https://github.com/mmbuw/mis-2018-exercise-4-opencv/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mis/opencv/MainActivity.java#L129-L139

Comment: Thank you for responding but I am already doing this. Still no luck